# Is there a list of special folders like named pipe (\\.\pipe\) on Windows

Tags: windows, file, winapi, named-pipes

I googled for named pipe and found Windows uses folders `\\.\pipe\` for named pipes. Does any one know if there is a list of such special folders? And what are the usage of those folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are not folders, but rather names in the "win32 device namespace", see [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx) for more details.

Other reserved names include the following:

From [`CreateFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx):

```
\\.\PhysicalDrive<#> 

\\.\<DriveLetter>:

\\.\Changer<#>

\\.\TAPE<#> 

\\.\COM<#>

CONIN$

CONOUT$
```

From [`CreateMailSlot()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365147.aspx):

```
\\.\mailslot\<name>
```

From [`CreateNamedPipe()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365150.aspx):

```
\\.\pipe\<name>
```

Comment: This is just what I want! Thanks!

Comment: Also note that WinObj (available for download from the MS web site) allows you to browse the kernel namespace.